# How to make paragraph into a string in python

Tags: python

Below is what I tried.

```
l = []

def makePara():
    with open("f:\\f2.txt", "r") as f1:
        for line in f1:
            l.append(line.split("\n"))

makePara()
print l
```

Below is what I am getting as output.

```
[['I    1,1', ''], ['love    1,2    3,3', ''], ['python    1,3    2,1', ''], 
['is    2,2', ''], ['very    2,3', ''], ['good    2,4    3,4']]
```

I want it to be in single line.

Comment: can you share the contents of the input file? How are you defining a paragraph?

Comment: Have you tried just reading the file with `f1.read()` instead of the loop?

Comment: line.split() returns a list, so you are appending a list to a list. Try extend instead of append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this might be what you are looking for

```
with open("f:\\f2.txt", "r") as f1:
    l.extend(f1.read().split("\n"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this works. Tweaked your own code. Slightly.

```
l = []
def makePara():
    with open("f:\\f2.txt", "r") as f1:
        for line in f1:
            l.extend((line.split("\n")))
    v=list(filter(lambda m: m != '', l))
    print(v)

makePara()
```